# Probability distribution of a random variable

Tags: r, distributions, ggplot2

The table below shows the number of ice creams brought and the number of customers brought that number of ice creams.

```
 ice_cream     No_of_customers
     1             225
     2             170
     3              55
     4              20
     5              20
     6              10
```

The estimated probability of purchasing the number of ice cream is shown below. e.g. probability of purchasing 1 ice cream is 225/500 = 0.45. This table below shows that distribution of number of ice cream sold

```
ice_cream    Probability
     1        0.45
     2        0.34
     3        0.11
     4        0.04
     5        0.04
     6        0.02
```

while showing this above distribution as a graph with the below code I was expecting my y- axis in histogram plot to have same values as in probability column

```
 ggplot(data = ice_cream)+
 geom_histogram(aes(x = ice_cream,y = ..density..))
```

I tried density plot but y axis is not the one in probability column for each ice cream column.
I am missing something very basic here.

Can someone please suggest how to get that probability in the graph?

Sample data:

```
ice_cream <- data.frame(ice_cream = c(rep(1,225),rep(2,170),rep(3,55),rep(4,20),rep(5,20),rep(6,10)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're not specifying the binwidth when constructing your histrogram even though the discrete nature of your data makes that critical. Try:

```
ggplot(data = ice_cream) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(x = ice_cream, y=..density..),
                   binwidth=1,
                   colour="black", fill="white")
```

Note that we specified `binwidth = 1`.

To see how things can go wrong, try setting `binwidth = 0.5` and observe what happens. As I wrote below in the comment, the problem with omitting `binwidth` entirely is that it will default to 30 bins and treat your data as continuous, so that you are now estimating a density of a continuous variable, which can certainly be greater than $1$ at certain regions. Here, at each of these $30$ bins that does not contain an integer, the density is $0$, and at bins that do contain an integer $k$, the density is $P(\text{icecream} = k)/\text{binwidth}$ and since $\text{binwidth} < 1$, this is inflating the numbers.

Comment: Thanks. That solve the problem. What does the value in y axis means if the bandwidth is not specified

Comment: When you don't specify binwidth or bins and run the code I provide, you get a warning message saying "`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`." So it's resorting to 30 bins, and treating the observed data as continuous. So then you're just seeing a histogram for continuous data, with y axis showing the density of a continuous distribution, which can certainly be greater than 1. Here, at each bin that contains an integer $k$, its doing something like $P(\text{icecream} = k)/\text{binwidth}$, and since binwidth < 1, it's inflating the numbers! Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks a ton for answering in intuitive way

Answer (score 2):

A couple ways to do this:

a) Plot the probability column using the probability column and geom_col

```
library(tidyverse)
ice_cream = 1:6
no_cust = c(225, 170, 55, 20, 20, 10)
d = tibble(ice_cream, no_cust)


d %>% 
  mutate(y = no_cust/sum(no_cust)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ice_cream, y))+
  geom_col()
```

b) uncount the ice creams

````
library(tidyverse)
ice_cream = 1:6
no_cust = c(225, 170, 55, 20, 20, 10)
d = tibble(ice_cream, no_cust)


d %>% 
  uncount(weights = no_cust) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ice_cream))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)))

```
````